# jqplot won't give me padding on my inner grid

Tags: javascript, charts, jqplot

We have a graph that looks like:

[image]

Very nice. Well, except for the first and last bars being split in half!

I know why it's doing it, but I don't know how to fix it. I've tried gridPadding, barPad, and Pad. Probably others. For whatever reason, I cannot seem to get them to push without prepending and appending some blank dummy data. Which makes an extra two confusing entries along the bottom, which is definitely not acceptable.

The code is as follows.

```
var f = [[0,1.29],[1,1.29],[2,1.48],[3,1.48],[4,1.48],[5,1.48],[6,1.48],[7,1.48]];
var v = [[0,0.71],[1,0.71],[2,0.8],[3,0.8],[4,0.8],[5,0.8],[6,0.8],[7,0.8]];
var p = [[0,-0.26],[1,-0.26],[2,0.67],[3,0.67],[4,0.67],[5,0.67],[6,0.67],[7,0.67]];

// [x position, y height]
var x_line = [[0,1],[1,21],[2,33],[3,39],[4,21],[5,21],[6,21],[7,21]];
var rank_ticks = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

$('body').on('click', '#load-fvp', function () {

    var plot2 = $.jqplot('fvp-chart', [f, v, p, x_line], {
        stackSeries: true,
        gridPadding: 40,
        highlighter: {
            show: true,
            tooltipAxes: 'y',
            useAxesFormatters: false,
            formatString: "<span style='display: none;'>%s</span> %s" // hide the first S because it's irrelevant
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                barWidth: 24,
                shadowAlpha: 0.03,
                fillToZero: true,
                highlightMouseOver: false
            },
            pointLabels: {
                show: true,
                stackedValue: true
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            location: 'nw',
            labels: ['Fund.', 'Value', 'Price', 'Rank']
        },
        series: [
                 {showLabel: true, useNegativeColors: false},
                 {showLabel: true, useNegativeColors: false},
                 {showLabel: true, useNegativeColors: false},
                  {
                    disableStack : true,//otherwise it wil be added to values of previous series
                    renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    pointLabels: {
                        show: false
                    },
                    color: '#FF7D7D',
                    markerOptions: {
                        size: 5, color: 'red'
                    },
                    xaxis: 'x2axis', yaxis: 'y2axis',
                  }
                  //, color: '#FFCC66', useNegativeColors: false, shadow: false, fill: false, lineWidth: 3, fillToZero: true
                ],

        axesDefaults: {
            //tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                ticks: rank_ticks,
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString:'%d',
                    fontSize:'7pt',
                    fontFamily:'\"Lucida Grande\",Verdana, Georgia, Times, serif',
                },
            },
            x2axis: {
                ticks: rank_ticks,
                showTicks: false
            },
            yaxis: {
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                ticks: [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                label: "Information Ratio",
                labelOptions: {
                  angle: 270,
                  fontFamily: "Verdana, Helvetica",
                  fontSize: "13pt",
                  textColor: '#111'
                },
                tickOptions: { 
                    formatString:'%d',
                    fontSize:'7pt',
                    fontFamily:'\"Lucida Grande\",Verdana, Georgia, Times, serif',
                },
            },
            y2axis: {
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                ticks: [100, 50, 1],
                showLabel: true,
                label: "Rank",
                labelOptions: {
                  angle: 90,
                  fontFamily: "Verdana, Helvetica",
                  fontSize: "13pt",
                  textColor: '#FF7D7D'
                },
                tickOptions: { 
                    formatString:'%d',
                    fontSize:'7pt',
                    fontFamily:'\"Lucida Grande\",Verdana, Georgia, Times, serif',
                },
            }
    }});

    $('.jqplot-table-legend').css('left', '567px').css('top', '-14px');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these values :

```
gridPadding:{
        right:40,
        left:40
    }
```